# Pivot Table PivotItems.Visible is always False on multi select

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to implement one-click pivot tables filtration (similar to [this one](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/01/03/change-all-pivot-tables-with-one-selection/)). It works great on single items but for some reason not on multiple items:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetPivotTableUpdate(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As PivotTable)

  Dim SourcePivotItem As PivotItem
  For Each SourcePivotItem In Target.PageFields(1).PivotItems
    If SourcePivotItem.Visible Then _
      MsgBox SourcePivotItem.Name + " is visible"
      ' Message box never pops when EnableMultiplePageItems=True
  Next SourcePivotItem
End Sub
```

Any ideas? Should I use different property on multiselect?

p.s: I'm using Excel 2013.

---

Random things I've tried that did not work:

```
Target.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
Target.PivotCache.Refresh
Target.RefreshTable
```

Comment: That post is quite old (year 2012) you should try PivotTable Slicers [Filter data in a PivotTable](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Filter-data-in-a-PivotTable-CC1ED287-3A97-4E95-B377-DDFAFE79FA8F)

Comment: Can you please explain more about "one-click" pivot table filtration. Which multiple actions should happen with single click? Maybe you could give an example?

Comment: @Taosique check out the link in the question. It contain explanations and a video of the required feature.

Comment: What if you just add a slicer that is connected to all the pivot tables in question?

Comment: Yes, connected slicers are ideal for this kind of feature.Unfortunately in this case the filtered list is long and slicer won't be comfortable since it's not collapsible and it doesn't feature a search box.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce... This code works for me and pops multiple MsgBoxes for each selected item.

Comment: Can you attach a sample s/s?

Comment: Tested your code. MsgBox works for each selected item as @Taosique already mentioned. Make sure the code is inside the workbook and not a worksheet. Add a msgbox at the start of the sub to see if it's called at all.